# How to use inotify to auto refresh a png file when the png file changed

Tags: inotify, image-viewers

I am trying to visualize some data, and my program outputs a png file. Each time when I modify my program, the output png file changes. So I hope to have an image viewer that can automatically reload the png file once it detects that the png file has changed on disk.

I have tried `eog` and `viewnior`, but none of them supports auto reload/refresh the image file. Can you suggest a better image viewer?

I think `inotify` is a good tool that should be able to do this, but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: I think we are missing a bit of context? What icon?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have provided more details about my problem.

Comment: Inotify could very well be used in a script to automatically reopen the file on changes, but reload in the currrent instance is impossible imo.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem while experimenting with imagemagick. So I have written a simple image viewer which updates itself (using inotify): https://gitlab.com/dknof/siv For compiling you need the gtkmm dev libraries, version 3. Just call siv with the image(s). You can scale them with the keys 1 - 0 and the mouse wheel.

Comment: Great job, dknof!  Your `siv` tool does exactly what I needed.  I had to install all of these: `clang libgtkmm-3.0-dev ccache` to get it to build.

Comment: Since this website is in English, you may want to mention that the description, documentation, and even source code comments are all in German, and will not be comprehensible to most of this website's visitors.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried `eog`

Current versions of `eog` *do* reload the image automatically. There is also a plugin which adds an explicit reload option, if you're using filesystems such as FUSE which do not support inotify.

`feh` now also has an `--auto-reload` switch which uses inotify, along with `--reload` which uses a simple timer.

Many more recommendations with this feature here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167808/image-viewer-with-auto-reload-on-file-change